# Returns null after accessing variables from Abstract methods

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstraction

I've got a question about my code. I have class Employee declared as abstract. Under it are 3 abstract methods, abstract String department, abstract int work_days and abstract void print_info.

Now, I created second class Tester that extends the Employee abstract class. I implemented the abstract methods.

```
abstract class Employee {

abstract String department();
abstract int work_days();
    abstract void print_info();

}



class Tester extends Employee{

String dept;
int work_days;

@Override
String department() {
    dept = "QA Department";
    return dept;
}

@Override
int work_days() {

    work_days = 5;
    return work_days;
}

@Override
void print_info() {
        System.out.println("Department :> " + dept + "Working Days :> " + work_days);
}




}




class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Employee emp_tester = new Tester();
    emp_tester.print_info();



}

}
```

Now, when I create instance for Tester and called print_info from Tester class, the variables dept and work_days returns null and 0.

Did I disobey rules in Abstraction? Any critics are much accepted. Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you have problems understanding what happens or is this just a question of good style/bad style?

Comment: hi Why are you calling abstract class method.You have already established is-A relations ship with Employee class.Create object of Tester itself and call method instead of going with dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: @Pradeep Common methods may go into Employee. Need abstraction

Comment: As per your code you don't have any body definitions for any methodsi.e No concreate methods.All are abstract.If you create a concreate method then it will give you the values.I didn't understand the question.As per the code your getting proper values.

Comment: @Pradeep May be not yet added. But this design looks ok to me

Answer (score 2):

You have implemented it correct and the values you seeing also correct.

When you have not assigned any values and print them, you get their default values.

For Objects, default is null and for  primitives their default.  You need to set them before you use them.

```
class Tester extends Employee{

String dept;
int work_days;

    public Tester(String dept, int work_days){
      this.dept = dept;
      this.work_days = work_days
    }
```

And then while creating a Tester,

```
Employee emp_tester = new Tester("Testing", 24);
```

Answer (score 1):

call your department function before printing.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Employee emp_tester = new Tester();
    emp_tester.department();
    emp_tester.work_days();
    emp_tester.print_info();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you call department() and work_days(), the member variables are not initialized now.
Why don't you add a constructor to initialize members?

```
Tester() {
  dept = "QA Department";
  work_days = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the values of `dept` or `workdays`.

You probably want to put lines like `dept = "QA Department";` in the constructor of the `Tester` class, if that is what their values are to be.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the getter insteat of accessing the properties:

```
class Tester extends Employee{

String dept;
int work_days;

@Override
String department() {
    dept = "QA Department";
    return dept;
}

@Override
int work_days() {

    work_days = 5;
    return work_days;
}

@Override
void print_info() {
        System.out.println("Department :> " + department() + "Working Days :> " + work_days());
}
```

Hint: Do not call the methods eqauls to the property names. If a value is returned, call the method `get...`

```
class Tester extends Employee{

String dept;
int work_days;

@Override
String getDepartment() {
    dept = "QA Department";
    return dept;
}

@Override
int getWorkdays() {

    work_days = 5;
    return work_days;
}

@Override
void print_info() {
        System.out.println("Department :> " + getDepartment() + "Working Days :> " + getWorkDays());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, default value for type String is null and for type int is 0.
That's why you get dept=null and workdays=0.

Answer (score 0):

As i think you have never initialized the values for the variables it will be null. You have to init the variables by calling `department()` and `work_days()` first, before accessing them.

Maybe you need to build a getter construct. This can ensure you that work-days/department will always been set when accessing the getter

Something looking like

```
int getWorkDays(){
    if(work_days == 0){
         //work_days(); use this instead of my example to call the overriden abstract method
        work_days = 5;
    }
    return work_days;
}
```

You can also write a getter for the Dept:

```
String getDept(){
    if(dept == null || dept.equals("")){
        //department(); use this instead of my example to call the overriden abstract method
        dept= "QA Department";    
    }
    return dept;
}
```

This getters should be used everywhere now like:

```
@Override
void print_info() {
        System.out.println("Department :> " + getDept() + "Working Days :> " + getWorkDays());
}
```

You can also call the methods to initialize the values in your Constructor like:

```
Tester(){
    work_days();
    department();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you will call method ,

```
String department()
int work_days()
```

with the same object , then only your property will get initilize. else, you need to initialize either using Constructor / SIB / IIB. Then after , you can call `print_info()` method to get the value displayed.